# How to rewrite this query to get the correct subtotal

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

As part of a process to load orders from Ebay, we dump an exported file into a table and then process the table with a stored procedure.  This works great for single item orders (even large quantities of one item) but it comes up with an incorrect subtotal on multiple item orders.  The reason is because of the query, but I'm stuck trying to find a way to get the right data without excluding things.

Here's an example of a single line item order (table shortened to show the point):

```
 Quantity | Sale Price | Shipping and Handling | Total
    2           $10          $4.95                $24.95
```

and here's a multi line one

```
 Quantity | Sale Price | Shipping and Handling | Total
    5         $60              $14.95             $74.95
    2         $10                             
    2         $15
    1         $10
```

Here is the existing query:

```
 SELECT @RecentUID, @MaxOrderNum, 
       CAST(REPLACE(`Sale Price`, '$', '') AS DECIMAL(20,5))* e.Quantity, 
       CAST(REPLACE(`Shipping and Handling`, '$', '') AS DECIMAL(20,5)), 
       CAST(REPLACE(`Sales Tax`, '$', '') AS DECIMAL(20,5)), 
       CAST(REPLACE(`Total Price`, '$', '') AS DECIMAL(20,5)), 
       STR_TO_DATE(`Paid on Date`, '%b-%d-%y'), DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR),
       'Process', 44, 'eBay Via PayPal', `Buyer Fullname`, `Buyer Address 1`,  
       `Buyer Address 2`, `Buyer City`,  `Buyer State`,  `Buyer Zip`
 FROM ebay_orders e
 WHERE e.`Sales Record Number` = @eBayOrderNumber
 AND e.`Paid on Date` <> ''
 AND e.imported = 0;
```

What happens is for the single line item, it takes quantity * sale price to get the subtotal value, which is correct.  However, for the multi-line items, it does not need quantity multiplied since Sale Price is already an aggregate of the other lines.

I'm at a loss for what to do.  This is a pretty complex query and I'm having trouble getting my head around where I need to put additional logic in to catch the multi-line case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I elected to do is this:

I set a variable

```
Set @Count = Select Count(*) from ebay_orders where `Sales Record Number` = $eBayOrderNumber
```

this will tell me if it is a single line order or a multi line order.  Then I just threw an if statement in there and repeated the code with the quantity bit removed.  Not as elegant as I hoped but it works.